# c2000 microcontroller sensorless speed control implementaion

Tags: texas-instruments, algorithm, pmsm

I want to know some detail about TMS320F28335 TI microcontroller for sensored and sensorless speed control of SPMSM. I have implemented the MATLAB simulation and the model is working well but for microcontroller I am getting problem how to introduce the interrupt.

Comment: too vague. more information needed

Comment: By sensorless do your mean an open-loop control?

Comment: Ah, ok, they have back-EMF sensing in each of the outputs of the board, so it is "sensorless".

Comment: not just bemf, there are some other ways as well for sensorless speed control because using bemf the low or zero speed control is difficult.

Answer (score 0):

I did a thesis using TI's C2000 for bldc. There are many docs, app note and example code from their website. Take a look at this [AN](http://www.ti.com/lit/an/sprabq5/sprabq5.pdf).

Download [ControlSuit](http://www.ti.com/tool/controlsuite), there are example code and docs.

Edited:

For implement Observer, I was using this way:

- First, you need install MATLAB [Embedded Coder](https://www.mathworks.com/hardware-support/ti-c2000.html) and Simulink coder, and choose target hardware
- Implement the Observer on MATLAB/SIMULINK, then generate code, then flash to your hardware.
- MATLAB's [Guide](https://www.mathworks.com/videos/getting-started-with-embedded-coder-support-package-for-ti-c2000-processors-1573540550102.html)

Comment: basically I would want to implement Luenberger observer for sensorless speed control of ipmsm using c2000 but I don't understand how should I implement it on the controller. I have studied different doc mostly related to epwm, adc and interrupt and check some code as well but I didn't get a lot of help. if you can mention some specific references or info in this regards

Comment: So, you should update the question. BTW i will give you better answer about implement the Observer.

Comment: thank, but I already go through the embedded coder and integrate both MATLAB and ccs but the issue is the control board that I am using is commercialized one that make issue with embedded coder

Comment: Understood. So there will be lots of work to do. You have to modeling and digitize your model based on sampling rate. You design Luenberger based on that model. Then you need to programming it. One question: why Luenberger ? Why not just PI with two loop. There are many method for estimate back EMF.

Comment: actually I am not estimating bemf, I am working on reduced order observer to estimate speed based on adaptive mechanism